# Minimum Difference in Date Range Android App Slider

Tags: android, slider

I am using [Range Seek Bar](https://code.google.com/p/range-seek-bar/) and I have effectively initialized a date range slider. How can I set the slider to have a minimum range difference of 10 years? My slider is from 1950-present. I only want to allow ranges with a minimum difference of years.

This is what I ended up did:

```
@Override
public void onRangeSeekBarValuesChanged(RangeSeekBar<?> bar, Long minValue, Long maxValue) {

    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy", Locale.US);
    int minYear = Integer.parseInt(formatter.format(minValue));
    int maxYear = Integer.parseInt(formatter.format(maxValue));
    //Log.i(getClass().getName(), "User selected new range values: MIN=" + minYear + ", MAX=" + maxYear);

    if ((maxYear - minYear) < 10) {
    //range is less than 10 years so we have to manually set it back.
        if (minValue != previousMin){
            //min is what changed
            mDateRangeSeekBar.setSelectedMinValue(previousMin);
        } else if (maxValue != previousMax) {
            //max is what changed
            mDateRangeSeekBar.setSelectedMaxValue(previousMax);
        }
    } else {
        //range was big enough so set previous values for next time.
        previousMin = minValue;
        previousMax = maxValue;
    }
    mMinDateTemp = new Date(mDateRangeSeekBar.getSelectedMinValue());
    mMaxDateTemp = new Date(mDateRangeSeekBar.getSelectedMaxValue());
    refresh();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the onChanged() callback to check the values for your range, if it is too small then set whichever value changed back to the previous one.

Something like this (I didn't compile, so you may have to fix typo's or small logic errors sorry):

```
//declare these in your activity
private int previousMin = -1;
private int previousMax = -1;

seekBar.setOnRangeSeekBarChangeListener(new OnRangeSeekBarChangeListener<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public void onRangeSeekBarValuesChanged(RangeSeekBar<?> bar, Integer minValue, Integer maxValue) {
        // handle changed range values
        Log.i(TAG, "User selected new range values: MIN=" + minValue + ", MAX=" + maxValue);
        if((maxValue - minValue) < 10){
            //range is less than 10 so we have to manually set it back.
            if(minValue != previousMin){
                //min is what changed
                seekBar.setSelectedMinValue(previousMin);
            }
            else if(maxValue != previousMax){
                //max is what changed
                seekBar.setSelectedMaxValue(previousMax);
            }
        }else{
            //range was big enough so set previous values for next time.
            previousMin = minValue;
            previousMax = maxValue;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: hi @hanleyhansen i tried but this solution is not working for me. any idea or suggestion.

Comment: @hanleyhansen what inside refresh() method